# How can we ensure the badge showing pending notifications is zero-ed on MobileFirst Platform 7.1?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with a client who's developing a hybrid application on MobileFirst Platform 7.1. When they send notifications to the iOS platform, they are successfully received and processed (i.e. the function assigned to `WL.Client.Push.onMessage()` is fired). However, the iOS "badge" (the count of pending messages on the home screen) is never reduced - it only increases over time. How can we ensure it is decremented/zeroed when notifications are consumed? Is there a callback function/API we need to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the WL.Badge API: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Badge.html?lang=en

You need to handle the badge on your own...